# If-statements Not Regonizing User Input

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm new to Python and coding in general. I'm trying to create a fill-in-the-blank quiz to practice. The first part asks the user to choose a difficulty. Once entered, the code appends an empty list. I'll use the list to load questions and answers. However, the issue I'm running into is the if-statements won't recognize user input. I want to make sure the user only inputs easy, medium, or hard. To see if the code worked, I used a print function. However, my code goes right to the else-statement and prints 'Try again.' Any ideas?

Here is my code.

```
choice = []

new_choice = raw_input('Select your quiz difficulty: Easy, Medium, Hard: ')
choice.append(new_choice)
print choice

if choice == 'easy':
    print 'True'
elif choice == 'medium':
    print 'True'
elif choice == 'hard':
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'Try again.'
```

Comment: You should probably be learning Python 3 if you are new to Python.

Comment: I'm about 3/4ths of the way through Udacity.com's programming course and they're teaching with 2.7.

Answer (score 2):

In its current form `choice` is a list, while you are trying to compare it to strings/text. Instead try this:

```
choices = []

new_choice = raw_input('Select your quiz difficulty: Easy, Medium, Hard: ')
choices.append(new_choice)
print choices

if choices[-1] == 'easy':
    print 'True'
elif choices[-1] == 'medium':
    print 'True'
elif choices[-1] == 'hard':
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'Try again.'
```

I renamed your list to `choices` to indicate that it holds multiple objects. `-1` let's you access the last thing you added to that list. So if you plan to store all the user responses to the list `choices`, you can perform a comparison against the last answer and proceed.

Comment: I'd probably rename the variable too (`choice` -> `choices`)

Comment: Great idea, shall add that!

Answer (score 1):

`choice` is a list containing your input, not the input. The user input you store into the `new_choice` variable. Try this

```
choice = raw_input('Select your quiz difficulty: Easy, Medium, Hard: ')
print choice

if choice == 'easy':
    print 'True'
elif choice == 'medium':
    print 'True'
elif choice == 'hard':
    print 'True'
else:
    print 'Try again.'
```

Comment: I don't want to sound needy, but because you are new to the site I'll remind you that if someone answers your question, it's polite to mark the answer as 'the answer' by clicking the checkmark next to the post. Happy trails on your adventure into programming!

Comment: I thought I did beforehand. When I do, it says my upvote is recorded but not displayed since I have less than 15 rep points.

Comment: Ahh, sorry then. I forgot the privileges of new users.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing lists to variables.

Maybe use:

```
variable = choice[0]
if variable == 'easy':
    # rest of program
```

Also, make sure that 'easy', 'medium', and 'hard' have no capital letters.

You can use:

```
new_choice.lower() # converts to lowercase
```

before appending to your list